# Mysqli convert varchar to date

Tags: mysql

I need to filter the registered emails by date of signoff but the problem is that the guy that made the database made the signoff column a varchar(255) and not a datestamp or something like that. 
Normally i would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM email WHERE signoff >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Is there any way to fix this without changing the datatype since there is already a lot of data in the database.

Comment: Fixing the column will take you 15 minutes. Writing workarounds forever is impossible to measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of performance its perhaps better to cast the comparison to string

```
$result = $dbhandle->query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE signoff >= CAST(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS CHAR(255));
```

But I will recommend, to just fix the column, if thats possible.

**You have to do the following steps**

1. Create a new Column signoffdate
2. Fill it with the values with the STR_TO_DATE function
3. Delete the old column
4. Rename the signoffdate to signoff

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this one's quite easy:

```
$result = $dbhandle->query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE str_to_date(signoff, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY");
```

Change the date format in str_to_date to match the date format in the varchar column.

Answer (score 0):

Year there is a function:

```
STR_TO_DATE('2011-12-21 02:20pm', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it . You can use STR_TO_DATE function like this:

```
$result = $dbhandle->query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE STR_TO_DATE(signoff , '%m/%d/%Y') >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY");
```